# Android Studio: findViewId not working with custom views

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I've read all the other questions relating to this, and most answers refer to all views, and the issue is usually with all views, but if I call findviewbyid for a built in view in the same place in code, it returns the view, but if I call it for a custom view, it just returns null. Both views are in the same place, in the same layout, have ID's, they are carbon copies inside the layout xml file. I correctly overridden all the constructors for the customView calling super(...) in each one. I am calling findViewById AFTER `setContentView`, and inside the Activity Class.

My question is, besides overriding the constructors, what else needs to be done to a custom view to allow it to be found by the function findViewByID? There has to be something missing.

```
protected void initClickCounter() {
    numberClicks = new DigitViewGroup(this);
    ImageDigitView v1;
    ImageView v2;

    v1 = (ImageDigitView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDigit1);
    v2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDigit1_2);
```

v1 is always null, while v2 is never null.

```
<com.bilowik.debugg.ImageDigitView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewDigit1"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="103dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/digit1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewDigit1_2"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="103dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/digit1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_0" />
```

They are identical besides the IDs.

```
public ImageDigitView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public ImageDigitView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    init(context);
}

public ImageDigitView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int  defStyle) {
    super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
    init(context);
}
```

The constructors for the ImageDigitView class.

Comment: Do you have some example code?

Comment: Do you have an error log?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this example:

```
View yourviewname = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);
Button expandableButton = (Button)yourviewname.findViewById(R.id.expandableButton1);
```

Comment: OK, now I understand. Thank you for your quick answer. I'm going to delete my comments here soon. I suggest you do it with your, as well. Have a nice day. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

get the **rootView** of your layout ,from that you can work out.
In Fragment:

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_x_layout, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
```